# Spacing between stars of Android RatingBar component

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I define the spacing between stars in the [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html) component?

Comment: kindly put your code?

Comment: Summarize the question + link to javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I have tried to do this programmatically but I dont think its possible IIRC.

The only way I managed to add padding to my stars is by adding empty space to my images.

After that I set my custom selector to my rating bar, like so:

```
android:indeterminateDrawable = "@drawable/custom_rating_bar"
android:progressDrawable = "@drawable/custom_rating_bar"
```

@drawable/custom_rating_bar :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+android:id/background"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star_empty" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
      android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</layer-list>
```

the custom_rating_bar.xml is placed in the drawable folder.

star_empty and star are images which I generated using the android 9 patch generator https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html
which generates my image for multiple screens sizes.

star_empty and star are placed in

drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi

the 9patch generator creates these folders so you just have to drag them to your res folder.

Hope this helps